# Image causing click event to fire twice?

Tags: google-maps, image, onclicklistener

I'm creating a Google map with markers and infowindows. I'd like each infowindow to have a zoom button that causes the Google map to zoom in and center and the corresponding marker.

See this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kqUwE/14/) for an example. The code for the infowindow is relatively simple:

```
infoWindowArray[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    position: latlng,
    content: "<a href='/"+pitches[i].slug+".html'>"+pitches[i].name + " ("+ pitches[i].club+")</a><br /><img width='16' alt='Loupe' src='//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/48/Loupe.svg/32px-Loupe.svg.png'/> <a id='zoom_"+pitches[i].id+"' href='javascript:void(0)'>Zoom In</a>"
});
```

However, my script is very temperamental in Chrome, and in Firefox it always fails. The reason is because *one* click is somehow being fired *twice*. So this function:

```
function setupZoomListeners(object, title, google_position, map){
    google.maps.event.addListener(object, 'domready', function() {
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById("zoom_"+title), 'click', function(){ 

            if (document.getElementById("zoom_"+title).innerHTML == "Zoom In"){
                map.setCenter(google_position);
                map.setZoom(14);
                document.getElementById("zoom_"+title).innerHTML = "Zoom out";
            } else {
                map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(53.5, -2.2));
                map.setZoom(6);
                document.getElementById("zoom_"+title).innerHTML = "Zoom In";
            }


        });
}
```

is zooming in and out because it hears two clicks, so the net effect is nothing. *However*, simply removing the img tag in the infowindow appears to solve all.

Is there any earthly reason why the presence of an img tag would cause the script to interpret one click as two? I've seen lots of cases where too many clicks are registered - what generally causes this?

Can anyone advise how to solve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Its capturing your *domready* event twice (at least in my version of firefox 19.0.2). You can see that if you start your *zoomListeners* function like so:

```
function setupZoomListeners(object, title, google_position, map){
    console.log('zoomListener');
    google.maps.event.addListener(object, 'domready', function() {
        console.log('domReady');
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(...
```

I don't think *domready* is a good event to be using here. Personally, I would just use one infoWindow object and populate with different HTML when the marker is clicked.

In any case, domready wasn't intended to be used for subsets of the dom as you are doing. I believe it's firing every time you change your markup. So when the lines starting `document.getElementById("zoom_"+title).innerHTML = ...` are executed the *domready* event will fire once again.